Issue with SVG Text Measurement: Inaccurate Width Calculations
I am encountering a problem with accurately calculating the width of text rendered in SVG format. The text width measurements obtained from the textbox are inconsistent with the dimensions in the generated SVG file. Specifically, I am facing the following issues:

Text Measurement Discrepancy: The width reported in the HTML does not match the actual width in the downloaded SVG file, often resulting in a difference of several centimeters.
Impact of Margins and Padding: It appears that the measurements include additional margins or padding that should not be accounted for, leading to incorrect width calculations. I require a solution that focuses solely on the actual vector outlines of the font.
Need for Accurate Path Conversion: I am looking for a way to convert the text to a path before measuring, ensuring that the outer dimensions are used directly without any external padding or margins interfering with the measurements.

Additionally, I am including my source code below for reference.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions that can help address this issue. Thank you!


let currentSVGContent = '';

        function updateText() {
            const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
            document.getElementById('textOutput').innerText = textInput;
            updateDimensions();
        }

        function updateDimensions() {
            const height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('heightSlider').value);
            document.getElementById('heightValue').innerText = `${height} cm`;

            const text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;

            // Calculate text dimensions using SVG
            const svg = document.getElementById('tempSvg') || createTempSvg();
            const textElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
            const fontSize = (height / 2.54) * 96; // Convert cm to px (96 DPI)
            textElement.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
            textElement.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
            textElement.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
            textElement.setAttribute('x', 0); // Reset X coordinate
            textElement.setAttribute('y', fontSize); // Reset Y coordinate
            textElement.textContent = text;

            // Append the SVG element
            svg.appendChild(textElement);

            // Remove the text element after measurement
            setTimeout(() => {
                const bbox = textElement.getBBox(); // Get actual dimensions
                const width = bbox.width;

                svg.removeChild(textElement); // Remove the text element

                document.getElementById('dimensions').innerText = `Height: ${height} cm, Width: ${(width / 96 * 2.54).toFixed(2)} cm`; // Convert px to cm

                // Update SVG content
                currentSVGContent = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${width}" height="${fontSize}" style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <text x="0" y="${fontSize}" font-size="${fontSize}" font-family="Arial" fill="black">${text}</text>
                </svg>`;
            }, 100); // Wait for 100 ms
        }

        function createTempSvg() {
            const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            svg.setAttribute('id', 'tempSvg');
            document.body.appendChild(svg);
            return svg;
        }

        function downloadSVG() {
            const blob = new Blob([currentSVGContent], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'text.svg'; // Name of the downloaded file
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // Release the URL
        }
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        #textOutput {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            white-space: pre-wrap; /* Preserve line breaks */
        }
        /* Hide the SVG */
        #tempSvg {
            position: absolute; /* To make it hidden */
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
    <label for="textInput">Enter Text:</label>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" oninput="updateText()" placeholder="Enter your text here">
    
    <h2>Select Height:</h2>
    <input type="range" id="heightSlider" min="30" max="150" value="30" oninput="updateDimensions()">
    <span id="heightValue">30 cm</span>
    
    <div id="textOutput"></div>
    <div id="dimensions"></div>
    
    <button id="downloadBtn" onclick="downloadSVG()">Download SVG</button>




Methouds like getBoundingClientRect() won't return a tight bounding box. You can use opentype.js to create a SVG path from a font and call it's boundingBox() method. See "How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?"

.getBBox() has no relation to  font-size and will change depending on the glyphs used. Where the top and bottom of every glyph are in relation to the font dimensions is totally at the discretion of the font designer. Also, the relation between cm and px is a configuration issue of your OS and can change.
